# Is there a way via CSS to set the image height to the line-height?

Tags: css

I have an image that's inline with text. That image is 32x32. I'm looking to have it *auto size* to the line height of where it's contained so it fits properly. Is there a way to do that?

I'm looking to be able to place the image anywhere with an unknown line height and have it resize properly.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Use `img{height: 1em;} /* whatever your line height may be, it is affected by its font-size /*`

See this **[Updated Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cpPLZ/3/)** (Increase or decrease the font size to view the result.)

Comment: This answer is not correct. 1em is the FONT size, not the LINE height. Different fonts have different line heights for the same font size! For example, for 12pt Times New Roman (the default font) 1em equals 16px, while the line height is 18.5px. For 12pt Verdana however, 1em also equals 16px, but the line height is 19.5px.

Comment: Any update, 9 years later?  Given the different between font-size and line-height as noted by @Peter ?

Comment: No, only of you explicitly set the line height. (Obviously, since then the line height is a known amount.)

Answer (score 13):

You can set the height to the line height if you explicitly set both, e.g.

```
* { line-height: 1.3; }
img { height: 1.3em; }
```

If you don’t want to set the line height, you would need to make a guess on browser defaults (which usually depend on font). This might be a good guess:

```
img { height: 1.12em; }
```

To make an image fit properly into text, so that it does not cause the actual line height to be increased, you would also need to align it vertically to the bottom of the line box, no to text baseline (which is higher):

```
img { vertical-align: bottom; }
```

If you need to let the image sit on the baseline (the default), you need to make a guess on the distance between the bottom and the baseline and set the image height accordingly smaller. In this case, `height: 1em`, or maybe with a little smaller value, might be a good guess.

Comment: Jukka's first example (setting the line height) is the only way to consistently set an image height to the line height. Also note that the relation between font size and line height not only differs per font, but may also differ between operating systems for corresponding fonts. So even if it fits on your computer, it might not on someone else's.