# How do I change the size of an image in css

Tags: html, css, image

I keep trying to change the size of my image with css by adding a width and height attribute. However, this only changes the zoom of the picture.

For example, I have a 90px by 90px image. However, when I change the width and height, it's like a zoomed in version of the pic instead of a smaller pic.

my css is:

```
.image-90 {
    horiz-align: center;
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    background-size: 90px 90px;
    margin: 10px;
    border: 1px rgb(218, 218, 218) solid;
    background: #C4C4C4 no-repeat 0 0;
    background-image: url('/Content/images/person_noimage.png? width=90&height=90&mode=crop');
}
```

here is my html (my image url is stored in Person.AvitarImage):

```
<div class="image-90" style="background-image:url-Person.AvitarImage"></div>
```

Comment: can you show your code..

Comment: What do you expect to happen? Changing the size of the image makes it larger or smaller.

Comment: Do you mean cropping the image?

Comment: No, I don't want to crop the image, I just want to make it smaller

Comment: can you show your html structure.

Comment: Change the background size... http://www.css3.info/preview/background-size/

Comment: I tried changing the background size but it didn't change anything

Comment: This Question May also help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15940338/is-there-a-way-via-css-to-set-the-image-height-to-the-line-height

Comment: Just add a height and a width

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`background-size` has to be declared *after* `background` and `background-image`. I'm not sure if it is true in all browsers, but it is something I noticed in Chrome and Firefox, at least. See http://jsfiddle.net/WS2qe/1/

If you set just one value, it is assumed to be the width and the height will adjust automatically to keep the background in proportion.

Comment: Thanks DavGarcia. That seemed to be the reason